# C++ Detect if a number is prime or not

Tags: c++

I cannot compile a reason as to why this code is not working. I am fairly new to C++, can anyone help? 
I get the error: " warning: control may reach end of
      non-void function [-Wreturn-type]"

And the function does not work correctly
(I am required to call a boolean function)

```
bool isprime(int num) {

    if (num == 2)
    return true;


    else if (num%2 == 0)
        return false;
}

int main()
 {

     int num,count=0;
     cout<<"Enter a number greater than 1 and less than 100: ";
     cin>>num;

          if (num<=1){
              cout<<"Oh nooooooooo, " << num << " is too small :(\n";
                return 0;
               }

          if (num>=100){
              cout<<"Oh nooooooooo, " << num << " is too large :(\n";
                return 0;
               }

            if  (isprime(num) == true) { 

           cout << "True " << num <<" is a prime number\n";   }

             else if (isprime(num) == false)  { 

             cout << "False " << num <<" is not a prime number\n";  }


return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? If it does not compile show a compilation error. If it gives the wrong output for some input tell us and use a debugger.

Comment: You don't have to call the function twice, an ordinary if-else statement is enough.

Comment: `isprime(3)` never reaches a `return` statement.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: This system would fail for a number like 15, where it isn't divisible by 2 but is for 3 and 5.

Comment: Not all paths of `is_prime` returns.

Comment: should be called `is_odd_except_2` as this is exactly what your function checks. Checking for primes is much more complex than this.

Comment: This is not prime number logic. This is even/odd (not properly) number logic

Comment: .....and there is no even prime number lol

Comment: @Tanner 2 is a prime number

Comment: Is 7 a prime? What will your function return? Is 9 a prime? What will your function return?

Comment: I don't think you have a C++ problem.. well, you have too, but your main problem is arithmetics and finding a correct procedure to calculate prime numbers. (Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your code is that you do not handle all possible cases in your isprime() function. There are numbers between 1 and 100 that are not evaluated: 3,5,7 and all further odd numbers.

-> Syntactically, the problem is that for these inputs there is not a return statement from your function.

-> Semantically, your function does not calculate whether those numbers are prime. For a conceptually rather easy algorithm to calculate primes, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 1):

The code is simply wrong. This does not check for prime numbers. I would suggest you read a math book that describes prime numbers and their properties in details before even attempting to write code to check for primes. What your function is doing is checking if the number is odd. Odd numbers are not necessarily primes, Take for example the number 9 which is not a prime yet your code defines it as such.

Answer (score -2):

The error means that it might reach the end of your function without returning anything.

Just remove the else if and have it return false.

Comment: It'll compiler but won't yield correct results.

Comment: It doesn't check for anything but being divisible by 2, you need to have it iterator to (1/2) of the number to tell if it's prime.

Answer (score -4):

Your logic for isprime is wonky. All even numbers are prime i.e. if(x%2==0) return(true);
In a loop test all odd numbers 3 upwards

if(x%odd==0) return(true);
else if(odd>=x) return(false);

This isn't an efficient method but it'll work.

Comment: Even numbers besides the number 2 are never ever primes. Primes by definition are numbers, larger than 1, that can only be divided evenly by itself and 1. Even numbers are always divisible by 2.